# How to setup Google Analytics for a total number of hits on three particular links on my website?

Tags: google-analytics

There are in particular three links on my website that I want Google Analytics to track for me.

I was wondering, how could I customize my Google Analytics to show metrics for those three link separately. Is their any guide?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics tracks all links by default. If you want to check how these 3 particular links are doing, you can look at the content. Here's how you reach there:

Standard Reports > Content > Overview > All Pages

Here, you will get a list of all the pages from your in a table. If your links don't show up here, you can add an "Advanced Filter" to the table.